# Control parameter structure via URL in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

Rails 6, Ruby 2.7

I've got a namespaced controller that is not tied to a model.

The route is `/api/v1/api_name/stores/:store_id/business_date`

The controller is `class Api::V1::ApiNameController`

Right now the parameters do not show the `:store_id` as belonging to the store, they just float at the top level.

`<ActionController::Parameters {"format"=>:json, "controller"=>"api/v1/api_name", "action"=>"business_date", "store_id"=>"32", "api_name"=>{}} permitted: false>`

Where as I'd like it to recognize that store is a model and nest it like

`<ActionController::Parameters {"format"=>:json, "controller"=>"api/v1/api_name", "action"=>"business_date", "store"=>{"id"=>"32"}, "api_name"=>{}} permitted: false>`

I've also tried setting the route as `/api/v1/api_name/stores/:id/business_date`
but no luck. Is there any standard way to get the params output I want here or do I just need to deal with `:store_id` being at the top level?

Comment: That is not how URL parameters work all URL parameters that are parsed out of the route will be top level as there would be no understanding of how to "nest" them. How should it determine the break point to provide the desired result? Why would it not be nested as `{api: {v1: {api_name: {stores: {id: 32}}}}}`? If you want your desired structure for a GET route you will have to pass that data as part of a query string e.g. `/api/v1/api_name/stores/business_date?store[id]=32`

Comment: I mean it could terminate on a matched model name, so I don't think there is any reason that couldn't be done but anyway thank you for confirming that it doesn't work this way